# Rubik's cube problem - Combinatorics required

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

There are $4.3\times 10^{19}$ combinations possible with a standard $3\times 3\times 3$ Rubick's cube.

My question is, if you would take 2 cubes and scramble them randomly, what are the odds of perfectly matching a single side on both cubes?

Comment: Do you mean a *face* or an *edge*? Do you want the probability of matching *at least* one, or *exactly* one?

Comment: I meant a face. Exactly one side.

Comment: This is not combinatorics.  Definitely a programming project which would be pretty involved (both time-wise and computational-wise).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: You need to sort out how many possible faces there are. Then find out how likely it is to get each face twice. This is a starting thought, not a total outline.